# how to fill missing seconds in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame I want to fill missing seconds values in Time data frame how to do that
this is my data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'sec': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'Date': ['7/7', '0', '0', '7/7', '7/7', '0', '7/7', '7/7', '0', '0'],
'Time': ['12:47:30', '0', '0', '12:47:33', '12:47:34', '0', '12:47:36', '12:47:37', '0', '0'],
'rpm': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
})
```

In Time column after 12:47:30 in place of 0 it has to be 12:47:31. In other words, my expected output is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'sec': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'Date': ['7/7', '0', '0', '7/7', '7/7', '0', '7/7', '7/7', '0', '0'],
'Time': ['12:47:30', '12:47:31', '12:47:32', '12:47:33', '12:47:34', '12:47:35', '12:47:36', '12:47:37', '12:47:38', '12:47:39'],
'rpm': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
})
```

Comment: Is the time column always sequential seconds?

Comment: yes, the time column is sequential only

Comment: @appu - some problem with solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `Time` column `.to_datetime` and add one second to previous time, as show below

**Code:**

```
# Convert 'Time' column to datetime and '0' values to NaT (Not a time)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')

# Iterate over the 'Time' column and replace NaT values 
# with the time by adding one second to the previous time
previous_time = None
for i, time in enumerate(df['Time']):
    if pd.isnull(time):
        new_time = (previous_time + timedelta(seconds=1))
        df.at[i, 'Time'] = new_time
        previous_time = new_time
    else:
        previous_time = time

df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

---

**Output:**

```
sec Date    Time    rpm
0   1   7/7 12:47:30    0.0
1   2   0   12:47:31    0.0
2   3   0   12:47:32    0.0
3   4   7/7 12:47:33    0.0
4   5   7/7 12:47:34    0.0
5   6   0   12:47:35    0.0
6   7   7/7 12:47:36    0.0
7   8   7/7 12:47:37    0.0
8   9   0   12:47:38    0.0
9   10  0   12:47:39    0.0
```

Comment: your response worked for me thank you

Answer (score 2):

Create `DatetimeIndex` first and then use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), last set columns values:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + df['Time'].astype(str), 
                          format='%m/%d%H:%M:%S', 
                          errors='coerce')

out = df.resample('S').first()

out['Time'] = out.index.time
out['Date'] = out.index.strftime('%m/%d')
out['rpm'] = out['rpm'].fillna(0)
out['sec'] = out.groupby('Date').cumcount().add(1)
print (out)
                     sec   Date      Time  rpm
1900-07-07 12:47:30    1  07/07  12:47:30  0.0
1900-07-07 12:47:31    2  07/07  12:47:31  0.0
1900-07-07 12:47:32    3  07/07  12:47:32  0.0
1900-07-07 12:47:33    4  07/07  12:47:33  0.0
1900-07-07 12:47:34    5  07/07  12:47:34  0.0
1900-07-07 12:47:35    6  07/07  12:47:35  0.0
1900-07-07 12:47:36    7  07/07  12:47:36  0.0
1900-07-07 12:47:37    8  07/07  12:47:37  0.0
```

---

```
out = out.reset_index(drop=True)
print (out)
   sec   Date      Time  rpm
0    1  07/07  12:47:30  0.0
1    2  07/07  12:47:31  0.0
2    3  07/07  12:47:32  0.0
3    4  07/07  12:47:33  0.0
4    5  07/07  12:47:34  0.0
5    6  07/07  12:47:35  0.0
6    7  07/07  12:47:36  0.0
7    8  07/07  12:47:37  0.0
```

Another solution with forward filling dates by [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) with add second for non times values created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + df['Time'].astype(str), 
                          format='%m/%d%H:%M:%S', 
                          errors='coerce')

sec = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(dates.notna().cumsum()).cumcount(), unit='s')

df['Time'] = dates.ffill().add(sec).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (df)
   sec Date      Time  rpm
0    1  7/7  12:47:30  0.0
1    2    0  12:47:31  0.0
2    3    0  12:47:32  0.0
3    4  7/7  12:47:33  0.0
4    5  7/7  12:47:34  0.0
5    6    0  12:47:35  0.0
6    7  7/7  12:47:36  0.0
7    8  7/7  12:47:37  0.0
8    9    0  12:47:38  0.0
9   10    0  12:47:39  0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, which uses linear interpolation to fill the null times:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
df_nonan = df[['sec', 'Time']].dropna()
f = interp1d(df_nonan.iloc[:, 0], df_nonan.iloc[:, 1],
             fill_value='extrapolate')
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(f(df['sec']))
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.time
```

Output:

```
   sec Date      Time  rpm
0    1  7/7  12:47:30  0.0
1    2    0  12:47:31  0.0
2    3    0  12:47:32  0.0
3    4  7/7  12:47:33  0.0
4    5  7/7  12:47:34  0.0
5    6    0  12:47:35  0.0
6    7  7/7  12:47:36  0.0
7    8  7/7  12:47:37  0.0
8    9    0  12:47:38  0.0
9   10    0  12:47:39  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your column always increments by one second, you can just "create" it with `pd.date_range`

The following line gives the desired output.

```
df['Time'] = pd.date_range(start='12:47:30', end='12:47:39', freq='s')
```

If you have a big dataset, instead of specifying the end, you can simply pass the number of values to create with the `periods` parameter.

Comment: i already tried this one with my original data, this solution is not worked

Comment: Well, you should have mentioned it so that we won't waste time retreading on tried solutions. Why does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that you want:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sec': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'Date': ['7/7', '0', '0', '7/7', '7/7', '0', '7/7', '7/7', '0', '0'],
    'Time': ['12:47:30', '0', '0', '12:47:33', '12:47:34', '0', '12:47:36', '12:47:37', '0', '0'],
    'rpm': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
})

# Create a mask for rows with '0' time values
mask = df['Time'] == '0'

# Find the index of the first non-zero time value
first_nonzero_idx = df.loc[~mask, 'Time'].index[0]

# Convert the 'Time' column to a list for easier manipulation
times = df['Time'].tolist()

# Fill in the missing time values by incrementing from the previous non-zero time value
for i in range(first_nonzero_idx + 1, len(times)):
    if mask[i]:
        prev_time = pd.to_datetime(times[i-1])
        times[i] = (prev_time + pd.DateOffset(seconds=1)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')

# Update the 'Time' column in the dataframe
df['Time'] = times

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   sec Date      Time  rpm
0    1  7/7  12:47:30  0.0
1    2    0  12:47:31  0.0
2    3    0  12:47:32  0.0
3    4  7/7  12:47:33  0.0
4    5  7/7  12:47:34  0.0
5    6    0  12:47:35  0.0
6    7  7/7  12:47:36  0.0
7    8  7/7  12:47:37  0.0
8    9    0  12:47:38  0.0
9   10    0  12:47:39  0.0
```

Comment: hello Omid don't post chat GPT generated answers here, some times chatGpt not giving correct responses

Comment: @appu It is completely developed by me and I have a notebook in Colab to test and develop, it took more than 10 minutes and I regret that I did that